# Java Exception: ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker incompatible with com.myco.TaskListEntry

Tags: java, multithreading, naming

In Java, I'm getting a cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
incompatible with com.myco.TaskListEntry
at com.myco.JobThreadFactory.newThread(JobThreadFactory.java:17)
```

Here's the code:

```
public class JobThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        TaskListEntry entry = (TaskListEntry)r;   //<== Cast exception!
        return new Thread(r, "Thread for " + entry.toString());
    }
}

@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class WorksheetSessionJob implements Job {
    private List<TaskListEntry> taskListEntries;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        ThreadFactory threadFactory = new JobThreadFactory();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(threadFactory);
        for( TaskListEntry nextEntry : getWorkListEntries() ) {
            executor.execute(nextEntry);
        }
    }

    private List<TaskListEntry> getWorkListEntries() {
        List<TaskListEntry> entries = new ArrayList<TaskListEntry>();

        // TODO Get rows from DB - for now, make something up to test with
        //-- beginning of fake data creation ----------
        TaskListEntry entry = new TaskListEntry("0022", "04590150560", "DI_MODULAR", 1);
        entries.add(entry);
        entry = new TaskListEntry("0007", "04590150560", "DI_MODULAR", 2);
        entries.add(entry);
        //-- end of fake data creation ----------------

        return entries;
    }

}

public class TaskListEntry implements Runnable {
    private String  worksheetNumber;
    private String  specimenNumber;
    private String  instrumentName;
    private int     id;

    public TaskListEntry(String worksheetNumber, 
            String specimenNumber, String instrumentName, int id) {
        super();
        this.worksheetNumber = worksheetNumber;
        this.specimenNumber = specimenNumber;
        this.instrumentName = instrumentName;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    synchronized public void run() {
        // executor in my Job should have created a thread for me to run in
        //-- TESTING ONLY -------------
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);    //force execution to another thread?
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //-- END OF TESTING -----------
    }

}
```

Why isn't my TaskListEntry runnable being sent? I need to use values from that class to name the corresponding thread.  What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the cast problem because when the thread factory is called, your `Runnable` is not associated with the `ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker` class.  The `Worker` `Runnable` is an internal executor class which dequeues tasks from the internal `BlockingQueue` which holds your `TaskListEntry` instances.  There is no way that your tasks can be associated with a particular thread by design.  If you submit 100k tasks into the queue, you would not want it to spawn 100k threads -- that's the whole point of using the thread-pool.

If you are trying to somehow track which threads are processing which tasks, I would suggest logging the thread-id (`Thread.currentThread().getId()`) inside of the `TaskListEntry.run()` method.  But if you are trying to see each task somehow in the thread-names, you aren't understanding how the thread-pool works.  Typically, I use a `ThreadFactory` to set the name on pool threads to identify the pool name.  Something like `"TaskListEntry pool-1"` or something would be an appropriate thread-name here.

If you explain more about what you are trying to accomplish with regards to the names, we may be able to provide more help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand what you're saying about the pool using smaller set of Thread instances over and over. What I am trying to do is have a more meaningful way of seeing what is happening/happened when debugging and especially looking at the log files after an issue.  Any suggestions for that?

Comment: As I mention in my answer Mark, I'd set a good name on the thread-pool threads to show them being associated with the `TaskListEntry` processing and log the thread-id in your logs to show what's being worked on.  That's about all you can do.